# Escaping $ in double quoted shell command

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, sqlplus

I can't find out, how to mask the $ in the following shell statement. Any
help is appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash
    
local result=`su -m user1 -c "sqlplus -s / as sysdba <<-EOF
  SELECT cdb FROM v\$database;
  exit
EOF"
`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should single-quote EOF, e.g. `<<-'EOF'`

But then you also need to run the subprocess with `$()` instead of backquotes.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
    
local result=$(su -m user1 -c "sqlplus -s / as sysdba <<-'EOF'
  SELECT cdb FROM v\$database;
  exit
EOF")
```

[BashFAQ/082](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) reports that “Backslashes (\) inside backticks are handled in a non-obvious manner”

```
$ echo "`echo \\a`" "$(echo \\a)"
a \a
$ echo "`echo \\\\a`" "$(echo \\\\a)"
\a \\a
# Note that this is true for *single quotes* too!
$ foo=`echo '\\'`; bar=$(echo '\\'); echo "foo is $foo, bar is $bar" 
foo is \, bar is \\
```

So if you do not want to use `$(...)` you need 2 backslashes, i.e. `\\$database` and if you want to use neither `$(...)` nor single-quoted EOF, you need no less than 6 backslashes, i.e. `\\\\\\$database`

Answer (score 1):

Do not use backticks. Use `#(...)`.

```
local result=$(su -m user1 -c "sqlplus -s / as sysdba <<-EOF
  SELECT cdb FROM v\\\$database;
  exit
EOF
")
```

But anyway, if you do not want anything to expand, use single quotes.

```
local result=$(su -m user1 -c 'sqlplus -s / as sysdba <<-EOF
  SELECT cdb FROM v\$database;
  exit
EOF
')
```

And you could, redirect in the parent shell - it's going to be way simpler - and use a quoted stop word.

```
local result=$(su -m user1 -c 'sqlplus -s / as sysdba' <<-'EOF'
  SELECT cdb FROM v$database;
  exit
EOF
")
```

Comment: ah ok, thank you :)